# Delete the cookie and protect route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I wrote this middleware and tested it with Postman and it works as it should.
But when I used an Axiox request on the browser I got some problems.

```
export const logout = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    res.cookie("token", "", {
      expires: new Date(0),
      path: "/",
      secure: true,
      httpOnly: true,
    });
    console.log("by by Cookie");
    successHandler(res, 200, "User logged out");
  } catch (error) {
    next(createError(404, "User not found"));
  }
};
```

On Postman, it deletes the cookie but it doesn't work on the browser.

I also created a protected route "cookie should be there to enter this route", but even when I delete the cookies manually it still accesses it.

```
router.route("/user").get(protect, getUserProfile)

export const protect = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  let token;
  token = req.cookies.jwt;
  if (token) {
    try {
      const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
      req.user = await User.findById(decoded.id).select("-password");
      next();
    } catch (error) {
      next(createError(401, "Not authorized, invalid token"));
    }
  } else {
    next(createError(401, "Not authorized, no token"));
  }
});

export const getUser = async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/auth/user");
    const data = await response.json();
    dispatch({ type: "LOGIN/SIGNUP", payload: data.data });
    console.log("getuser F end");
    return data.data;
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({ type: "LOGOUT" });
  }
};
```

I tried to move between Axios and the fetch method.